# Relational DatabaseError in django postgresql database after deploying project to bitnami

Tags: django, postgresql, deployment, bitnami

I am deploying my django project using amazon ec2 and the bitnami-djangostack ami.

While I was developing the app locally I used mysql. But after deploying the project I used the default for bitnami postgresql.

Now I am getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "appName_appName" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "appName_appName" WHERE "appName_a...
                           ^
```

I don't know why the database is naming the database twice (appName_appName).

here is the full terminal:

```
bitnami@dom:/opt/bitnami/projects/Project$ sudo python manage.py syncdb
/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py:60: DeprecationWarning: Short names for ENGINE in database configurations are deprecated. Prepend default.ENGINE with 'django.db.backends.'
  DeprecationWarning
/opt/bitnami/projects/Project/cookbook/models.py:94: DeprecationWarning: A Field class whose db_type method hasn't been updated to take a `connection` argument.
  class JSONField(models.TextField):
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table registration_registrationprofile
Creating table south_migrationhistory

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yesa
Please enter either "yes" or "no": yes
Username (Leave blank to use 'root'): xxxx
E-mail address: xxxxx
Password: xxx
Password (again): xxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.6-py2.6.egg/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 90, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 109, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 190, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 70, in create_superuser
    call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 134, in handle
    User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 140, in create_superuser
    u = self.create_user(username, email, password)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 136, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 570, in save_base
    created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/opt/bitnami/projects/Project/cookbook/models.py", line 68, in create_cookbook_for_user
    if created and not instance.cookbooks.exists():
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 192, in exists
    return self.get_query_set().exists(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 424, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "appName_appName" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "appName_appName" WHERE "appName_a...
                               ^
```

thank you,
katie

Comment: "database is naming the database twice" -> "django is repeating the table name twice" ? Also, Django version?

Comment: What does the function create_cookbook_for_user in your code do? looks like it's hooked up as a signal and that's the point where the failure is happening.

Comment: when you join the site, you(a user) are given a cookbook. so that function creates the cookbook instance related to that user

Comment: i am using django 1.3. I ended up just adding the app to the database manually and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the appname_appname to my database and it now works fine.

sorry to mislead - my mistake. I still don't understand why the piece of code wasn't being added to the database on syncdb to begin with though.

but all is well now